# Image input type not showing empty value in Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css

I am using the below code for displaying a button as an image as defined in CSS. For most browsers, the button renders correctly, but in Chrome and Safari, the value `Submit` displays in front of the button. How do I make that text go away?

```
<input name="color" type="image" class="btn" value="" />
```

Comment: <input name="color" type="image" class="btn" value=""/>

Comment: Where is your css? Providing more codes will help us to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to reflect answer given in the comments:

```
<input name="color" type="image" class="btn" value=" " />
```

Comment: i am using like this only

<input name="color" type="image" class="btn" value=""/>

Comment: I updated my answer with a new guess based on that information.

Comment: but the image displayed using sprite concept.thats why the src given in css.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Have you tried `value=" "`? Is the image rendering correctly besides having the text on top of it?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nRSZ9/). You need to provide us with more code.